# PointF array has all values the same

Tags: c#, arrays, point

On every new click I get new coordinates and save them in *points* but it also changes old values. For example

First click: points[(156, 25), (0, 0), (0, 0)]

Second click: points[(85, 92), (85, 92), (0, 0)]

Third click: points[(15, 120), (15, 120), (15, 120)]

```
PointF[] points = new PointF[3];
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   points[angle] = new PointF(Location.X, Location.Y);
   angle++;
}
```

Comment: Where does `angle` initialized? please include all the relevant code in your question.

Comment: What if I click on the form *fourth* time? Answer: `OutOfRangeException`...

Comment: This was only an example of code. The problem was that I was using Location.X instead of e.X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use e.X and e.Y, not Location, because Location is the Location of the form.

Comment: Thank you so much!